# PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR: column "oauth_expires_in" of relation "users" does not exist (in Rails 5)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, migration, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm getting the following error **trying to remove a column I have just created**.

> PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR: column "oauth_expires_in" of relation
>   "users" does not exist

Here my first migration file.

```
20170709013540_add_oauth_expires_in_to_users.rb
class AddOauthExpiresInToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    add_column :users, :oauth_expires_in, :integer
  end
end
```

Which created consequently this new column in my table "users" in schema.rb

```
create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string   "email",                  default: "",    null: false
  t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "",    null: false
  t.string   "reset_password_token"
  t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
  t.datetime "remember_created_at"
  t.integer  "sign_in_count",          default: 0,     null: false
  t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
  t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
  t.inet     "current_sign_in_ip"
  t.inet     "last_sign_in_ip"
  t.datetime "created_at",                             null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at",                             null: false
  t.string   "name"
  t.string   "oauth_token"
  t.string   "oauth_secret"
  t.string   "photo"
  t.boolean  "admin",                  default: false, null: false
  t.integer  "oauth_expires_in"
  t.index ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true, using: :btree
  t.index ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true, using: :btree
end
```

Then I created a new migration file to remove the column I created. See below:

```
20170709111539_remove_oauth_expires_in_from_users.rb
class RemoveOauthExpiresInFromUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    remove_column :users, :oauth_expires_in, :integer
  end
end
```

And when I run the migration I get the following error:

```
== 20170709111539 RemoveOauthExpiresInFromUsers: migrating ====================
-- remove_column(:users, :oauth_expires_in, :integer)
rails aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column "oauth_expires_in" of relation "users" does not exist
: ALTER TABLE "users" DROP "oauth_expires_in"
/Users/davidverbustel/code/davidverbustel/barky/db/migrate/20170709111539_remove_oauth_exp    ires_in_from_users.rb:3:in `change'
./bin/rails:4:in `require'
./bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column "oauth_expires_in" of     relation "users" does not exist
: ALTER TABLE "users" DROP "oauth_expires_in"
/Users/davidverbustel/code/davidverbustel/barky/db/migrate/20170709111539_remove_oauth_exp    ires_in_from_users.rb:3:in `change'
./bin/rails:4:in `require'
./bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column "oauth_expires_in" of relation "users" does not exist
/Users/davidverbustel/code/davidverbustel/barky/db/migrate/20170709111539_remove_oauth_exp    ires_in_from_users.rb:3:in `change'
./bin/rails:4:in `require'
./bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => db:migrate
```

I have been scratching my head for a while but cannot spot the mistake?!.

Any idea would be much appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: * Works for me (tm). Whats the exact Rails Version? 
* Have you checked if the column is actually added to the DB?
* You do not need to specify the type (:integer) when removing
* Shouldn't the statement generated be "ALTER TABLE users DROP COLUMN oauth_expires_in" ?

Comment: Like @pascalbetz said, check whether it was added in the first place. Also, hope you didn't remove the column manually from table which is through psql or pgadmin or something similar.

Comment: I'm using rails 5.0.
Thanks for the tips @pascalbetz Using rails dbconsole I can see that the column is missing BUT thru rails console, I can create a user with the attribute 'oauth_expires_in'.
How can it be different between both? Can I brut force the whole thing by removing the migration file and removing the line in schema.rb?

Comment: You can also do `rake db:migrate:status` and see if the migration(s) in question actually ran successfully in the first place.

Comment: Seems like your migrations are out of sync? Can you drop/recreate the whole DB? What happens when you exit from Rails console and start a new one?

Comment: Yes, they were. I ran rake `db:migrate:status` and the migration was `down`. I tried to `rake db:migrate:up VERSION= xxx ` without success on my local machine but did managed to run the migration on production. So production env is now fine and for my local env I had to reset the database.
Thanks the help folks!